# Make Actionsheet button open another ViewController?

Tags: xcode, ios6

Someone gave me this code, is it correct? if so how do i use it? I am a noob so can you explain in simpler terms for me? Thanks guys :)

```
- (IBAction)OpenActionSheetButton:(id)sender {


UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"There is no going back,
 are you sure???" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
 destructiveButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[actionsheet showInView:self.view];}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:
(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == 0)
{
UIViewController *controller =  [self.storyboard 
instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"storyboardViewIdentifier"];
    //storyboardViewIdentifier is the ViewController identifier you specify in the
storyboard

    //PUSH
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    //Modal
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:Nil];
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with the case with storyboard, but with the case of XIB, I need to set UINavigationController object as rootviewcontroller, so that I can push from one viewcontroller to another, I think in storyboard it may be the same, if so, see these answers, [first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11980440/1603234) and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8539824/1603234) to set navigation controller as rootviewcontroller in storyboard environment.